# Javascript For loop to retrieve only the first eventdate from google calendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, google-calendar-api

Below my home.html file, the script does the following:

- Link the website to a google calendar API
- Retrieve dates and names of rocket launches

My issue is, since the calendar for the same rocket has multiple launches in the same month, I want it to be where the loop only pushes the next incoming launch/event (instead, it pushes only the last, skipping all the others before).

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Here below the data from Google Calendar API.

```js
Array(25)
0
: 
{name: '(NET) Hanbit-TLV  • Test Flight', eventdate: '12/15/2022 12:00 AM'}
1
: 
{name: '(NET) Kestrel I • Test Flight', eventdate: '12/15/2022 11:00 PM'}
2
: 
{name: 'Long March CZ-11 • Shenjian 2013', eventdate: '12/16/2022 6:00 AM'}
3
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5 • SWOT', eventdate: '12/16/2022 11:46 AM'}
4
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5 • O3b mPOWER 1–2', eventdate: '12/16/2022 9:21 PM'}
5
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5 • Starlink 3557–3610', eventdate: '12/16/2022 9:54 PM'}
6
: 
{name: 'Electron • Hawk 6A/B/C', eventdate: '12/16/2022 11:00 PM'}
7
: 
{name: 'Vega C • Pléiades Neo 5–6', eventdate: '12/20/2022 1:47 AM'}
8
: 
{name: '(NET) Terran 1 • Test Flight', eventdate: '12/25/2022 12:00 AM'}
9
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5 • Starlink', eventdate: '12/28/2022 8:19 AM'}
10
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5 • EROS C3-1', eventdate: '12/29/2022 6:58 AM'}
11
: 
{name: 'Long March CZ-3B/E • BeiDou 54–55', eventdate: '12/30/2022 6:00 AM'}
12
: 
{name: '(NET) SSLV • TBD', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
13
: 
{name: '(NET) RS1 • CubeSats', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
14
: 
{name: '(NET) LauncherOne • Prometheus 2A/B & Amber 1', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
15
: 
{name: '(NET) Vulcan VC2S • PM1 & Kuipersat 1–2', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
16
: 
{name: '(NET) Falcon 9 B5 • SARah 2–3', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
17
: 
{name: '(NET) Falcon 9 B5 • WorldView Legion 1–2', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
18
: 
{name: '(NET) PSLV XL • Aditya-L1', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
19
: 
{name: '(NET) Atlas V 551 • NROL-107', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
20
: 
{name: '(NET) Nuri • TBD', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
21
: 
{name: '(NET) GSLV Mk.II • NVS 1', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
22
: 
{name: '(NET) Vega C • TBD', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
23
: 
{name: '(NET) GSLV Mk.II • EOS 5', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
24
: 
{name: '(NET) Falcon 9 B5 • SES 18 & SES 19', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
length
: 
25
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
(index):561 
Array(5)
0
: 
{name: 'Electron', eventdate: '12/16/2022 11:00 PM'}
1
: 
{name: 'Falcon 9 B5', eventdate: '01/01/2023 12:00 AM'}
2
: 
{name: 'New Shepard', eventdate: ''}
3
: 
{name: 'SpaceShipTwo', eventdate: ''}
4
: 
{name: 'Gaofen 14', eventdate: ''}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}
{%include "Base.html"%}



<!-- cache eraser -->
<header>
  <meta name="propeller" content="12bebe3bdb5972b07a2a0340874adcdb">
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
</header>
<!-- fonts link and css/html link -->

<head>
  <script type="text/jquery" language="jquery">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("body").addClass("animated hinge");
   });
    var versionUpdate = (new Date()).getTime();
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "../static/js/script.js?v=" + versionUpdate;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  </script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@900&display=swap');
  </style>

  <!-- For google calendar integration -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function printCalendar() {
      var calendarId = 'xxx';
      var apiKey = 'xxx';
      var userTimeZone = "UTC";
      gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': apiKey,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
      }).then(function () {
        return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': calendarId,
          'timeZone': userTimeZone,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(), //gathers only events not happened yet
          'maxResults': 25,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        });
      }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.result.items) {
          var calendarRows = ['<table class="wellness-calendar"><tbody>'];
          var events = [];
          var startsAt;
          var endsAt;
          response.result.items.forEach(function (entry) {
            if (entry.start.dateTime != undefined) {
              startsAt = moment.utc(entry.start.dateTime).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(entry.start.dateTime).format("LT");
            }
            if (entry.start.date != undefined) {
              startsAt = moment.utc(entry.start.date).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(entry.start.date).format("LT");
            }
            if (entry.start.dateTime != undefined) {
              endsAt = moment.utc(entry.end.dateTime).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(entry.end.dateTime).format("LT");
            }
            if (entry.start.date != undefined) {
              endsAt = moment.utc(entry.end.date).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(entry.end.date).format("LT");
            }
            calendarRows.push(`<tr><td>${startsAt} - ${endsAt}</td><td>${entry.summary}</td></tr>`);
            console.log(entry.summary);
            event = {};
            if (entry.summary) {
              event["name"] = entry.summary;
              event["eventdate"] = startsAt;

              events.push(event);
             
            }

          });
          console.log(events);
          setAllEvenDates(events);
          console.log(arrElements);
          setAllInterval();
          calendarRows.push('</tbody></table>');
          $('#wellness-calendar').html(calendarRows.join(""));
        }
      }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    };

    // Loads the JavaScript client library and invokes `start` afterwards.
    gapi.load('client', printCalendar);
  </script>

  <script>

    var arrElements = [
      { "name": "Electron", "eventdate": "" },
      { "name": "Falcon 9 B5", "eventdate": "" },
      { "name": "New Shepard", "eventdate": "" },
      { "name": "SpaceShipTwo", "eventdate": "" },
      { "name": "Gaofen 14", "eventdate": "" }
    ];

    function setAllEvenDates(arrEvents) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrEvents.length; i++) {
        setEventDate(arrEvents[i].name, arrEvents[i].eventdate);
      }
    }


    function setEventDate(eventname, eventdate) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrElements.length; i++) {
        if (eventname.search(arrElements[i].name) != -1) {
          arrElements[i].eventdate = eventdate;
        }
      }
    }

    function setAllInterval() {
      //return;
      // Update the count down every 1 second
      var x = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrElements.length; i++) {
          if (arrElements[i].eventdate != "") {

            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var countDownDate = new Date(arrElements[i].eventdate).getTime();
            // console.log("prova:",(arrElements[i].eventdate).getTime()) 
            var distance = countDownDate - (now - 3600000);
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById(arrElements[i].name).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
            // console.log("test:",arrElements[i])
            if (distance < 0) {
              document.getElementById(arrElements[i].name).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

            }

          }
          if (arrElements[i].eventdate == "") {
            document.getElementById(arrElements[i].name).innerHTML = "UNSCHEDULED";
          }
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

  </script>

</head>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Reposting a deleted question is one of the ways to get rid of downvotes. Another way would be to pay attention to phrasing and spend some time to articulate the desired outcome.

Comment: Dear @Parzh from Ukraine, I never deleted this question, I've just added a bounty to it, hoping somebody will give me some hints:), or even a solution.

Comment: Indeed, the other question is [still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735660/for-loop-to-iterate-only-the-first-element-of-the-array)

Comment: Ideally you would post a raw JSON response from the google API as noone here can test your code snippet...

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the previous if to consider the startDate of the event and update existing events to the earliest startDate.

```js
.then(function (response) {
if (response.result.items) {
  var calendarRows = ['<table class="wellness-calendar"><tbody>'];
  var events = [];
  var startsAt, endsAt;
  var startDate, endDate;
  response.result.items.forEach(function (entry) {
    startDate = entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date;
    endDate = entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date;

    if (startDate) {
      startsAt = moment.utc(startDate).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(startDate).format("LT");
    }
    if (endDate) {
      endsAt = moment.utc(endDate).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(endDate).format("LT");
    }

    calendarRows.push(`<tr><td>${startsAt} - ${endsAt}</td><td>${entry.summary}</td></tr>`);

    console.log(entry.summary);
    if (entry.summary) {
      const ev = {
        "name": entry.summary,
        "eventdate": startsAt,
        "start": startDate,
        "end": endDate,    
      }

      const exIndex = events.findIndex(e => e.name == ev.name);
      if(exIndex) {
        if(events[exIndex].start > ev.start) {
          events[exIndex] = ev;
        }
      } else {
        events.push(ev);
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(events);
  setAllEvenDates(events);
  console.log(arrElements);
  setAllInterval();
  calendarRows.push('</tbody></table>');
  $('#wellness-calendar').html(calendarRows.join(""));
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, is still giving me the last event on the calendar instead of the incoming one.

Comment: How about now then? I've rewritten more of the code to ensure the earliest startDate is used.

Comment: No, unfortunately, pasting your code, is not allowing to retrieve data from calendar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': apiKey,
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
}).then(function() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': calendarId,
        'timeZone': userTimeZone,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(), //gathers only events not happened yet
        'maxResults': 25,
        'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.result.items) {
        var calendarRows = ['<table class="wellness-calendar"><tbody>'];
        var events = [];
        var startsAt, endsAt;
        var startDate, endDate;
        response.result.items.forEach(function(entry) {
            startDate = entry.start.date || entry.start.dateTime;
            endDate = entry.end.date || entry.end.dateTime;

            if (startDate) {
                startsAt = moment.utc(startDate).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(startDate).format("LT");
            }
            if (endDate) {
                endsAt = moment.utc(endDate).format("L") + ' ' + moment.utc(endDate).format("LT");
            }

            calendarRows.push(`<tr><td>${startsAt} - ${endsAt}</td><td>${entry.summary}</td></tr>`);
            // arrElements names list here
            const name = ["Electron", "Falcon 9 B5", "New Shepard", "SpaceShipTwo", "Gaofen 14"].find(item => entry.summary.search(item) !== -1)
            if (name) {
                const ev = {
                    "name": name,
                    "eventdate": startsAt,
                    "start": startDate
                }

                // Element with same name index
                const exIndex = events.findIndex(e => e.name == ev.name);

                if (exIndex !== -1) {
                    // check if previous entry had date greater than the new entry if so then new entry will replace old
                    if (moment.utc(events[exIndex].start).isAfter(moment.utc(ev.start))) {
                        events[exIndex] = ev;
                    }
                } else if (moment.utc(ev.start).isAfter(moment.utc())) {
                    // else push only if date is greater than current date
                    events.push(ev);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, pasting your code, is not allowing to retrieve data from calendar.

Comment: can u update some sample data? that would be great for debugging

Comment: I did it. I also insert the google calendar address. Hope will help...

Comment: please check now, it should work